# Home design thermal efficiency

Tags: discussion

If I just asked about thermal efficiency would this be a good question for this site?

[build up or build out](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/138935/design-up-2-story-or-out)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I think it would be a decent fit.

You could extend it to be not just about thermal efficiency, but about overall energy efficiency, including the embodied energy of the building materials too, if you wanted to.